# Using ASIS3ObjectRequest to upload multi parts to Amazon-S3 in iOS?

Tags: iphone, file-upload, amazon-s3, asihttprequest, chunks

I had uploaded file to Amazon-S3 server, its working fine. but i want to upload multiple parts like Total_Content_length(file) = 1000, i need to split (1000/5) to upload, Please provide any sample code or any suggestion for it. Is it possible to do?

Thanks in Advance

I had tried to upload file:

```
    [ASIS3Request setSharedSecretAccessKey:secretKey];
    [ASIS3Request setSharedAccessKey:awsAccessKeyId];
     NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"notification" ofType:@"png"];
    ASIS3ObjectRequest *request =
    [ASIS3ObjectRequest PUTRequestForFile:filePath withBucket:@"myApp" key:@"/TempImage/notification.png"];
    [request startSynchronous];
    if ([request error])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",[[request error] localizedDescription]);
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Sucess");
    }
```